# Поиск по паре ключ-значение

Tags: c++, stl

Имеется список на multimap пара ключ-значение. В списке присутствуют не уникальные значения. Необходимо добавить новую пару ключ-значение, если таких нет в списке. Метод find ведет поиск только ключу. Может есть возможность искать именно по ключ-значение?

Comment: у Вас получается, что ключем является "ключ-значение". Так может их объединить и хранить все в set? (то есть, использовать что то вида `std::set<std::pair<key,value>>`)

Comment: Потом делать операцию по разделению, накладно)

Comment: Из std::pair? Никаких сложностей и накладных расходов.

Comment: Я про лишнюю операцию

Comment: Только правильные бенчмарки покажут истинну.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря, ваша структура данных не очень приспособлена для организации
подобного поиска. Тем не менее, есть предложение использовать комбинацию двух
поисков. Вначале воспользуемся методом **std::multimap::equal_range**,
сложность которого логарифмическая, и найдём все пары с искомым ключом, затем
выполним линейный поиск подходящего значения с помощью **std::find_if**. Стоит
заметить, что таким образом найдётся лишь одна их подходящих пар.

Пример:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, char> dict {
        {1, 'A'},
        {2, 'B'},
        {2, 'C'},
        {2, 'D'},
        {4, 'E'},
        {3, 'F'},
    };

    // Производится поиск пары {2, 'C'}
    auto range = dict.equal_range(2);
    auto pair = std::find_if(range.first, range.second,
                             [](auto& el){ return el.second == 'C'; });

    if (pair != range.second) {
        std::cout << "Найденo!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Нету подходящих элементов" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: В принципе я к этому и склонялся. Спасибо.